# Observers podem ser injetados no observable?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, observer-pattern

É uma pergunta meio besta cuja resposta pode ser que seja "faça o que fizer mais sentido no código", mas não custa perguntar.

O padrão *Observer* sugere que um observador se cadastre (via `observable.registerObserver(observer)` ou `observable.addObserver(observer)`, é a mesma coisa) junto ao observável para receber eventos e similarmente se descadastre por meio de um `observable.unregisterObserver(observer)` ou `observable.removeObserver(observer)`).

Porém em certas situações pode ser necessário injetar o observador no observável, o que é menos dinâmico. Penso no caso de uma classe observável `SocketHandler`, que encapsula um `Socket` TCP já aberto do lado do servidor e encapsula também uma `Thread` que é iniciada imediatamente após uma nova conexão ser aceita. Nesse caso não parece haver oportunidade de cadastrar o observador; a classe `SocketHandler` logo se autentica através do protocolo que implementa (o que é um dos eventos que interessam ao observador, portanto este já deve estar cadastrado) assim que a thread é iniciada.

No exemplo abaixo não confunda os listeners (observers) da classe `Server` com o observer da classe `SocketHandler`, que se chama `commandSender` e está sendo injetado na classe `SocketHandler` conforme citado na pergunta.

```
class Server {
    ...

    private void acceptConnectionsLoop() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // bloqueante
                SocketHandler socketHandler = new SocketHandler(socket, 20, commandSender);
                socketHandler.start();
            
                listeners.forEach((listener) -> listener.onNewHandler(socketHandler));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

O objetivo todo é que um `SocketHandler` autenticado faça parte de uma lista que possa receber comandos e transmiti-los ao cliente que está conectado.

Então fica aqui a pergunta: é melhor ser mais "purista" e tentar de alguma forma implementar um observer que se cadastra e descadastra ou devo optar pelo caminho menos dinâmico de injetar logo o observer no observável?